# parseJSON class method with dependent type

Tags: haskell, typeclass, aeson

and thanks in advance for the help :)

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

I have a type (`MyType`) and I wrote a JSON parser for it (Using aeson library), and this parser depends on another value (`Config`):

```
import Data.Aeson

data MyType = MyType Text
data Config = Config Text

parseMyType :: Config -> Value -> Parser MyType
parseMyType (Config f) (Object o) = do (String v) <- o .: f
                                       return $ MyType v
```

What I **really** wanted to write a `FromJSON` instance for it... but the `parseJSON` only depends on the `Value` (cannot have Config):

```
instance FromJSON MyType where

    parseJSON :: Value -> Parser MyType
    parseJSON = ???
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to use type class in this case. I'm probably missing some type trick... or maybe there's a language extension I can use?

Thank you!

Comment: `data MyBetterType = MyBetterType MyType Config` ?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this gonna work.. I need the Config value before, in order to make decisions inside the Parser monad.

Comment: Looks like MyType should just have a parser defined in terms of withText and the larger thing containing MyType should provide the field name from which to parse MyType.

Comment: Can you just perform operations on the JSON AST to transform it into the correct shape before handing it to `parseJSON`?  Then you can have a funciton `applyConfig :: Config -> Value -> Value` and so you can have `parseJSON . applyConfig config` for performing the parse.  You still won't get to use `decode`, but that's not a huge deal IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "magic up" an instance declaration based on runtime information, this is possible through the `reflection` library, though it is some rather deep magic and there is probably a nicer way: https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection